# Update from table A to table B on ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

How to update set QTY = balanceqty
sql

```
SELECT
    balanceid,
    balanceqty,
    id,
    qty
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            lotxlocxid.id balanceid,
            SUM(lotxlocxid.qty) balanceqty,
            lotxlocxid.status AS balancestatus,
            id.id,
            id.qty,
            id.status
        FROM
            wmwhse1.lotxlocxid left
            JOIN (
                SELECT
                    id.id,
                    SUM(id.qty) AS qty,
                    id.status
                FROM
                    wmwhse1.id
                GROUP BY
                    id.id,
                    id.status
                ORDER BY
                    id.id
            ) id ON lotxlocxid.id = id.id
        WHERE
            lotxlocxid.qty > 0
        GROUP BY
            lotxlocxid.id,
            lotxlocxid.status,
            id.id,
            id.qty,
            id.status
        ORDER BY
            lotxlocxid.id
    )
WHERE
    balanceqty - qty != '0'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOMsM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merge statement to update qty column from wmwhse1.id table like below.

```sql
merge into wmwhse1.id tgt
using(
  SELECT
      balanceid,
      balanceqty,
      id,
      qty
  FROM
      (
          SELECT
              lotxlocxid.id balanceid,
              SUM(lotxlocxid.qty) balanceqty,
              lotxlocxid.status AS balancestatus,
              id.id,
              id.qty,
              id.status
          FROM
              wmwhse1.lotxlocxid left
              JOIN (
                  SELECT
                      id.id,
                      SUM(id.qty) AS qty,
                      id.status
                  FROM
                      wmwhse1.id
                  GROUP BY
                      id.id,
                      id.status
                  ORDER BY
                      id.id
              ) id ON lotxlocxid.id = id.id
          WHERE
              lotxlocxid.qty > 0
          GROUP BY
              lotxlocxid.id,
              lotxlocxid.status,
              id.id,
              id.qty,
              id.status
          ORDER BY
              lotxlocxid.id
      )
  WHERE
      balanceqty - qty != '0'
)src
on(tgt.id = src.id)
when matched then update set tgt.qty = src.balanceqty
where tgt.qty = src.qty
;
```

Comment: Glad to see I could help